# How to print to this effect so that after cut it is A5 size book?

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a pdf, it is A4 size, page by page, a small book (Actually a long journal paper). I want to print it out so that it looks like a small book.But the size of the book should be A5. I dont have A5 paper in my printer, so I am thinking to print it on A4, double sided, and in some way, and then cut them into two, so that after doing this I can combine them together into a A5 size book.

Any ideas how to do this sort of printing in a pdf reader? Or any software I can use? Or if on Linux, anyone knows how to write a scripts to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Reader has a function "Booklet Printing".
[Take a look at the Adobe-website.](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-booklets-acrobat-reader.html)